# Android - Jar integration - Either Dalvik Error 1 or Unable to resolve superclass

Tags: java, android, pdf, jar, superclass

I am integrating a Jar file into a test project, to accomplish *PDF* file reading. This is the library I am trying to integrate:

https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library

---

I need to add a jar file and derive the activity from there. Firstly let me say, i have not worked with integrating .jar files, so I might have done something wrong at the "deriving the activity". Though by now I think I have tried all possible ways of getting this to work.

I have a made a new file - PdfReader:

```
package net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class PdfReader extends PdfViewerActivity {

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public int getNextPageImageResource() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPdfPageNumberEditField() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I Run Eclipse 3.7.2 and ADT18 - Target Android 2.1. 
I am aware, there are issues around ADT17 / ADT18 with integrating Jar's.

I have now gone through all sorts of combinations and most of the ones, which should be working from what I read on other pages, gives me a Dalvik 1 error.

I can make make it launch without a Dalvik 1 error, by setting putting the Jar file as a part of the project + Add Jar from there. Then eclipse is happy. But when I  start the function in AVD, I get the unable to resolve superclass error.

(+)
By setting the added .Jar file as exported, inside the build path menu, I get a Dalvik 1 Error.

If i place the jar in the libs folder (import directly) to Android Dependencies, i get a Dalvik 1 Error.

I have tried to import the project to my old laptop, which had ADT15 on it, and there I get "Unable to resolve superclass".

I need suggestions of what else to try, because I have been sitting and looking at this for a week now, without getting anywhere... :-/

---

This is the error I get in AVD

---

```
06-04 00:40:47.636: D/ddm-heap(236): Got feature list request
06-04 00:40:47.716: W/dalvikvm(236): Unable to resolve superclass of Lnet/sf/andpdf/pdfviewer/PdfReader; (27)
06-04 00:40:47.716: W/dalvikvm(236): Link of class 'Lnet/sf/andpdf/pdfviewer/PdfReader;' failed
06-04 00:40:47.716: E/dalvikvm(236): Could not find class 'net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfReader', referenced from method net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.Niels.onClick
06-04 00:40:47.716: W/dalvikvm(236): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 26 (Lnet/sf/andpdf/pdfviewer/PdfReader;) in Lnet/sf/andpdf/pdfviewer/Niels;
06-04 00:40:47.716: D/dalvikvm(236): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x000a
06-04 00:40:47.716: D/dalvikvm(236): Making a copy of Lnet/sf/andpdf/pdfviewer/Niels;.onClick code (124 bytes)
06-04 00:41:17.527: D/AndroidRuntime(236): Shutting down VM
06-04 00:41:17.527: W/dalvikvm(236): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
06-04 00:41:17.527: E/AndroidRuntime(236): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-04 00:41:17.536: E/AndroidRuntime(236): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfReader
06-04 00:41:17.536: E/AndroidRuntime(236):  at net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.Niels.onClick(Niels.java:44)
```

---

Here is the way that leads to the DALVIK 1 Error:

---

Sorry for the link, but I can't post images here yet:

```
  http://euroturbo.net/tester_problem.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates it couldn't find the class when you tried to run the application.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(236): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfReader
```

Make sure that `PdfViewer.jar` exists in the `/libs/` folder in your project.

Once you've added the `JAR` file to the folder it should automatically be picked up by the build tools, you may have to `Refresh` (<kbd>F5</kbd>) the project in Eclipse for it to show in the `Android Dependencies` section.

Comment: Hi Antew. This has been tried and i have now also set a link to a picture showing the way i am doing what you suggest.

Comment: So a lot of people has been viewing, but only 1 answer.. Anyone who has any suggestions is very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue. It seems i was "doubling" some terms due to the names i had been used for the packages/classes. Created a new project with different names.

Comment: How is the performance of the lib. I have asked a question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613783/opening-pdf-in-android-using-andpdf-jar-extremely-slow . It seems to be extremely slow for me