# Opening pdf in Android using ANDPDF jar extremely slow

Tags: android, pdf

I am using this https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library - Basically a wrapped jar for the andpdf viewer for Android. I am not able to open a single pdf even though I 've followed the activity creation instructions to the letter.It alsways shows pdf loading. It is the only one I can use since it is under LGPL and I have to incorporate it in my proprietary project. The other ones I ve found either use MuPDF which is under GPL or use itext and only can be used to create PDF's. I've raised this issue on both andpdf and the wrapper sites but havent received responses.Has anyone solved this performance issue wrt ANDPDF. OR has anyone used a jar under LGPL to open pdf's in android?

For the andpdf jar - I am passing the path  to the file as a URI to the function in the Jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - Actually I was passing the file Name to the wrong activity - It has to be passed to the activity in the Jar and not to the locally created activity

Comment: It's nice that you solved your "not loading" bit, but I'm pretty sure it is still extremely slow in opening any non-trivial PDF.

Comment: It is not even slow, sometimes its not even working properly. Did you find any other good library, Please share it. Its urgent.

Comment: Nope sorry - i went with using intents and starting existing pdf viewers. Either build your own or use intents or buy commercial licenses.